# how to resize flexbox?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0QpK.png)[need to know how to create that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeRAh.png)

have tried using CSS but I just don't really understand the main code to use?

Comment: Try using two divs side by side

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: have actually attempted it

Comment: @half of a glazier do you mean like this? <div class="image">
    <div class="img-div">

    <img src="images/image-header-mobile.jpg" alt="image">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Get insights that help your business grow.</h2>  

  <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
    experience, and overall efficiency.
  </p>
  <p>10k+ companies
    314 templates
    12m+ queries
  </p>
</div>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The CSS property you're searching for is probably Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

But I'd rather recommend CSS Grid as the browser support is awesome nowadays and it will make some things easier: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

But in this case: It's just a flex container with two flex items.